# Boost VS Drupal Cache

Tags: performance, caching

I'm using Boost and Drupal internal cache on two different websites and i m remarking that the [site](http://dardiafa.ma) with internal cache is more quickly than the [site](http://sahara-question.com/en) with the Boost module .
So I'm asking which between the two methodes are suitable ?
Thank  you very much

Comment: This needs more information. Boost, properly configured, skips a Drupal bootstrap (and actually avoids all PHP) entirely, so would always be faster than the built in cache. However, Boost is certainly not a drop-in module. It requires customizing the `.htaccess` file among other things.

Comment: i already well configured my boost module and edited my htacess file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boost bypasses execution of Drupal's PHP and serves static files.  So unless you have other problems, it should always be much faster than the standard Drupal cache.  Be aware that it only works for anonymous users.

View source on your pages when running boost and make sure they have a comment at the end that says cached by boost.  Boost puts that comment there by default.  If you haven't disabled it, and it's not there, boost isn't working properly.  It's usually caused by incorrect or missing .htaccess rules.  If you don't see this comment, you won't see an error on the status page.  Your site will work normally, but is not being cached.

It looks like this:

```
</body>
</html>
<!-- Page cached by Boost @ 2012-10-30 15:01:23, expires @ 2012-10-31 15:01:23 -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much but where exactly i have to see the boost comment? because i installed the module like it is indicated and the drupal status is fine, thank you

Comment: Added example to answer.  You may not see an error on the status page if your .htaccess rules are not correct.

Comment: Here is how i did: i copied the code generated by the boost module and i past it into the .htaccess file

Comment: Yes and on certain server configurations I've seen that not work.  Are you seeing the comments in the source?

Comment: Unfortunatley no

Comment: Ok, then the default htaccess rules aren't working for you.  I've seen this happen on some share hosts where the default paths are not correct.  There are a bunch of options you can try on the settings page.  Regenerate the rules and try again.  You'll need to log out and refresh the page at least once before you'll see the comment.

Comment: Please tell me if i'm wrong:For my boost configuration i am using for Servers URL or Name: %{HTTP_HOST} for Document Root: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} In another way, i'm confused by what do you mean by the root of the web server :i'm hosting my website in a host company and i dropped my drupal files in the 'www' folder ,that mean that my index.php is at www/index.php . So should i modify the 'www/.htaccess ' file or the .htaccess situated at the same level as the www folder

Comment: Modify the one at www/.htaccess.  I'm not sure if HTTP_HOST or DOCUMENT_ROOT are correct.  It depends on the host.  On one host I use, I had to manually enter the path on their filesystem because none of the options were correct for mod_rewrite to work.

Comment: If you are using Cloudflare you will not see any comments in your source. That could make you think that boost is not working/configured properly. If you are using Cloudflare, visit your site in the direct subdomain assigned (without Cloudflare).